# 3D Plot - Color function depending of Z value (If statement?)

Tags: plotting, functions, graphics3d, color

Consider the well-known peaks function :

```
M1[x_, y_] := 3*(1 - x)^2*Exp[-x^2 - (y + 1)^2] - 10*(x/5 - x^3 - y^5)*Exp[-x^2 - y^2] - 1/3*Exp[-(x + 1)^2 - y^2]
```

and a surface function defined as :

```
M2[x_, y_] := Height
```

I would like to create a "failure domain" with all graph values above the surface defined by `Height`. The values being above the surface should take a red color.

[image]

For now I've tried something like :

```
Plot3D[M1[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, If[z > Height, Red, Blue]]]
```

But nothing seems to append.

The whole code :

```
BR = {1, 1, 0.6};
VP = {-1.5731187519157273`, -2.86538067256667`, 0.8745804672255597`};
VV = {-0.028375104870160164`, -0.05239698268451681`, 0.9982231261742867`};
IS = 500;
AE = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}};
PS = {Directive[Automatic], Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.2]]};
Height = 2.5;
M1[x_, y_] := 3*(1 - x)^2*Exp[-x^2 - (y + 1)^2] - 10*(x/5 - x^3 - y^5)*Exp[-x^2 - y^2] - 1/3*Exp[-(x + 1)^2 - y^2]
M2[x_, y_] := Height

Plot3D[{M1[x, y], M2[x, y]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
  PlotRange -> Full, Mesh -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 6, BoxRatios -> BR, 
  ViewPoint -> VP, ViewVertical -> VV, Boxed -> True, PlotStyle -> PS, 
  ImageSize -> IS, AxesEdge -> AE, BoxStyle -> Dashed]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`. Otherwise your values are scaled 0...1. Further, `PlotPoints` ensure nicer boundaries between red and blue.

```
Plot3D[M1[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, If[z > 3, Red, Blue]], 
 PlotPoints -> 200, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you also need `ColorFunctionScaling->False`.

For a simpler example, try

```
f=x*Exp[-x^2];
cf=Function[{x,y},If[y>0,Red,Blue]];
Plot[f,{x,-3,3},ColorFunction->cf]
Plot[f,{x,-3,3},ColorFunction->cf,ColorFunctionScaling->False]
```